# Kendo Server Side Grid: Custom Buttons

Tags: kendo-ui, grid

What is the correct way to bind custom buttons (class glyphicons) to Kendo columns / toolbars?

```
.ToolBar(tb =>
              {
                  tb.Template("<button type=button id=gridTrainerAdd><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign'></span></button>");

              })
```

works but icon looks quite differen than expected (probalby nested css problem).

How do I use buttons in columns? During researches I only found quite different solutions for client side grids...

What would this (compare columns button "View details") be in server side (fluent) notation?:

```
    $(function () {
      var grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: {
          pageSize: 20,
          data: createRandomData(50)
        },
        sortable: true,
        columnMenu: true,
        pageable: true,
        height: 430,
        columns: [
          { field: "FirstName", title: "First Name", width: "140px" },
          { field: "LastName", title: "Last Name", width: "140px" },
          { field: "Title" },
          { command: {
            text: " View Details",
            click: showDetails,
            className: "fa fa-map-marker"
          },
           title: " ",
           width: "140px"
          }],
          dataBound: function (e) {
            e.sender.tbody.find(".k-button.fa").each(function(idx, element){
              $(element).removeClass("fa fa-map-marker").find("span").addClass("fa fa-map-marker");
            });
          }
      }).data("kendoGrid");
```

I'd expect somthing like:
    columns.Command(com => com.Custom());

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding k-button and k-button-icontext classes to your button. It will give the button the kendo theme styling.

```
tb.Template("<div class='toolbar'><a class='k-button k-button-icontext k-grid-add' href=''><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign'></span>add</a></div>");
```

**Update:**
You can add custom css to the button in MVC with the `HtmlAttributes` method.

```
columns.Command(command =>
{
    command.Edit();
    command.Destroy();
    command.Custom("Copy").Click("CopyPOLine").HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "k-copy-icon"});
}).Width(175);
```

**Update2:**
Also you should check out the [custom command demo](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/custom-command) on the kendo ui website. Here is part of the example copied below.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Kendo.Mvc.Examples.Models.EmployeeViewModel>()    
    .Name("Grid")
    .Columns(columns => {
        columns.Bound(e => e.FirstName).Width(140);
        columns.Bound(e => e.LastName).Width(140);
        columns.Bound(e => e.Title);
        columns.Command(command => command.Custom("ViewDetails").Click("showDetails")).Width(180);
    })    
.HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height: 400px;" })
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
    .Ajax()
    .PageSize(20)
    .Read(read => read.Action("CustomCommand_Read", "Grid"))
 )
)

<script type="text/javascript">
var detailsTemplate = kendo.template($("#template").html());

function showDetails(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var dataItem = this.dataItem($(e.currentTarget).closest("tr"));
    var wnd = $("#Details").data("kendoWindow");

    wnd.content(detailsTemplate(dataItem));
    wnd.center().open();
}
</script>
```

Comment: Yes thx, I am aware of that. But I am struggeling with the server side syntax.

Comment: Not really sure I understand what problem you are having. Maybe you could add some more details to your question.

Comment: Thx this works fine. But for binding just single icons this approach is no solution. I guess I have to use template instead of Custom ?